# How to store current time in registry?

Tags: c++, time, mfc, registry

Is there a way I can store time in registry? I am using MFC and working with CTime objects (which allows me to use CTimeSpan to calculate time difference) but any c++ solution would be great.

Comment: The internal of a `CTime` object is simply a `__time_64t`, which you should easily be able to store in a registry key.

Comment: What problem are you having with storing the CTime object? Are you just looking for pointers to MFC's registry classes? Or is there an issue you're trying to overcome?

Comment: @jwismar MFC registry functions writes either an int or string but I know time is a larger value so not sure which api to use.

Comment: @zadane a string (or a binary blob, which I guess is a "string" of sorts) is what you want - check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would recommend that you use [`CTime::Serialize64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h2z537bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to use the built-in MFC serialization. Alas, MFC offers no easy way to serialize data to the registry...

You have two options:

You can either go the route that Shaktal recommends in his comment by using [`CTime::GetTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3s7y67z7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get back a `_time64_t`.

You can then write that value to the registry (but convert it to a string first) with [`CWinApp::WriteProfileString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/t453x0d8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). When you need it, read it back into a string using [`CWinApp::GetProfileString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/62txabd8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get the string back, convert it to a `_time64_t` and assign that resulting value to your `CTime` instance using `=`.

Or you can use [`CTime::GetAsSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hcc89tce%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get the date and time in your `CTime64` instance back as a `SYSTEMTIME` structure. You can then write that `SYSTEMTIME` in the registry with [`CWinApp::WriteProfileBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czdbx46h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

To read it back later, simply read the registry entry into a `SYSTEMTIME` with [`CWinApp::GetProfileBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60e44e56%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and pass the `SYSTEMTIME` to the appropriate [`CTime` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b6989cds%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Although this might seem more tedious that the solution involving `_time64_t` it has some advantages in how corner cases are handled (e.g. daylight savings time, timezones, etc) which may (or, more likely) may not be important for your application.

I'd give you an example, but I'm typing this on an iPhone and it's not the ideal interface for this sort of thing.